# Extract JSON from string in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, regex, extract

The input string is mix of some text with **valid** JSON:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<TITLE>Title</TITLE>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="en">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="keywords" CONTENT="search words">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">

<script SRC="include/datepicker.js" LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>
<script SRC="include/jsfunctions.js" LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>

<link REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="css/datepicker.css">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
{"List":[{"ID":"175114","Number":"28992"]}
```

The task is to deserialize the JSON part of it into some object. The string can begin with some text, but it surely contains the valid JSON. I've tried to use [JSON validation REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/tA9pM8/1), but there was a problem parsing such pattern in .NET.
So in the end I'd wanted to get only:

```
{
    "List": [{
        "ID": "175114",
        "Number": "28992"
    }]
}
```

**Clarification 1:**
There is only **single** JSON object in whole the messy string, but the text can contain {}(its actually HTML and can contain javascripts with `<script> function(){.....` )

Comment: Well... you can just use Json.NET

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I've tried to, but it can't deserialize the string properly.. So I must somehow tell the JSON.NET how to parse it.

Comment: Why does the text before and after the JSON portion exist? Can the text contain `{` and `}`? If not then the simple solution would be to find the 1st and last bracers and assume that is the start and end of your JSON. Otherwise I'd say you are screwed since you wont be able to tell where the actual JSON starts.

Comment: Maybe there are some restrictions on that text? For example, can it contain "{" character?

Comment: @Theo Text can contain valid HTML, so it can contain Javascript and {} in it. Probably Im screwed here and should ask the provider to refine the response.

Comment: If you're certain that there is only one JSON object in each string, you can Split the string and append together everything between the first `{` and the last `}`.  That sounds pretty messy but it's the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Is the json in one line or is it with line breaks as the sample above?

Comment: @Evk i've asked for JSON, but the client made view with JSON in its content, so there are header/footer parts of the HTML left that are not visible, when you open the view, but are visible when you actually get the response (with cURL and not in browser, for example) :(

Comment: @MatiasCicero there are linebreaks. But there is ONLY ONE JSON in whole string.

Comment: @maniak1982 yes, there surely is only single JSON object in whole string. I'll try your suggestion, thank you

Comment: You are screwed, as even `{}` is valid json and chances are there that your html-containing text contains things that could be an actual json out of context. However you might try to use a DOM-parser to extract your JSON from the HTML, if you have a clue where it is placed. You might be even more screwed, if your JSON is formatted with HTML :X

Comment: I've updated the question with almost the real HTML that I have.

Comment: Ok, probably will stick with dumb solution here: find the index of {"List" and get the substring from it to the end of the string.

Comment: That is a less than optimal solution. If/When whoever is providing that data adds annother `{"List"` it will stop working and you (or some other poor soul) will be expected to fix it. Better to correct the problem at the source now, rather than wait for it to fail and apply another band aid.

Comment: @Theo , see the accepted answer, that did the trick I wanted: extracted the JSON alike string and then tried to find the match without exception. Seems more beautiful solution than the one I was going to stop by. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regex to find all possible JSON structures:

```
\{(.|\s)*\}
```

[Regex example](https://regex101.com/r/FHB1Lg/1)

Then iterate all these matches unitil you find a match that will not cause an exception:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(match);
```

If you know the format of the JSON structure, use [JsonSchema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm).

Comment: Thanks! With few refinement that's better solution than magic with substrings!

Comment: This regex may be dangerous because it may create catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Thanks @Chrile  It doesnt work for the complex json with the nested structure.

Comment: Can someone add the regx that also works for json array (array of json object)?

Answer (score 7):

You can use this method

```
    public object ExtractJsonObject(string mixedString)
    {
        for (var i = mixedString.IndexOf('{'); i > -1; i = mixedString.IndexOf('{', i + 1))
        {
            for (var j = mixedString.LastIndexOf('}'); j > -1; j = mixedString.LastIndexOf("}", j -1))
            {
                var jsonProbe = mixedString.Substring(i, j - i + 1);
                try
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonProbe);
                }
                catch
                {                        
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The key idea is to search all { and } pairs and probe them, if they contain valid JSON. The first valid JSON occurrence is converted to an object and returned.

Comment: I was going to do almost such thing by finding the occurrences of '{' by hand and then to match some properties. The accepted answer seems more proper to me. Thank you for your time and help too!

Comment: @0x49D1 - You are welcome. Just an additional thought: It might be better to probe from the longest match to the shortest (I am not sure, if there is a defined order in the regex matches). If there is no fixed order, then a subpart of the JSON might be recognized as valid JSON as well.